# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list' when using pyimgui.plot_lines()

Tags: python, user-interface, cython, pyimgui

Here is my code:

```py
import imgui
foo = [0.9, 1.1, 1.3, 2.5]

imgui.begin()
imgui.plot_lines("Plot", foo)
imgui.end()
```

And it gives me this error:

```
File "imgui\core.pyx", line 6042, in imgui.core.plot_lines
  File "stringsource", line 660, in View.MemoryView.memoryview_cwrapper
  File "stringsource", line 350, in View.MemoryView.memoryview.__cinit__
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'
```

I tried converting `foo` to a `np.array` or to a `array.array` by doing `imgui.plot_lines("Plot", np.array(foo) or array.array(foo)` but it didn't work, I was expecting a plot to appear in my window.

Comment: when converting `foo` to `numpy.array`, it gives me this error: `ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'const float' but got 'double'`

Comment: If you have more information to add, click the `Edit` button and put it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of `plot_lines` is:

```
def plot_lines(
        str label not None,
        const float[:] values not None,
        int values_count  = -1,
        int values_offset = 0,
        str overlay_text = None,
        float scale_min = FLT_MAX,
        float scale_max = FLT_MAX,
        graph_size = (0, 0),
        int stride = sizeof(float),
    ):
```

`values` is a 1D Cython memoryview of type `float` meaning that what you pass to it must be an object that supports the buffer protocol with a **32 bit** floating point number. Both Numpy arrays and `array.array` can meet that criteria if the underlying type is set correctly, however  `np.array(foo)` creates an array of 64-bit floating point numbers by default. `list` fails because it doesn't support the buffer-protocol.

There look to be examples of calling `plot_lines` in the package: https://github.com/pyimgui/pyimgui/blob/480b4de8ab82adaa2cd310100330b41f40274bcc/doc/examples/plots.py#L21-L40.

They pass an `array.array` but specify the type as a 32-bit float. In your example this would be:

```
array.array('f', foo)
```

Alternatively you could specify the type of a Numpy array with

```
np.array(foo, dtype=np.float32)
```

---

The other thing you'll probably need to do (I haven't tested it myself!) is to actually create a window to draw in. The [documentation says](https://pyimgui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/first-steps.html)

> The bare `imgui.core` module is not able to render anything on its own. The `imgui.render()` function just passes abstract ImGui drawing commands to your rendering backend. In order to make it work you will first have to initialize the rendering backend of your choice.

The code example for `plot_lines` that I linked to above looks to use `GLFW` as the backend.